DialogueEvent not registering DialogueEventListener to list of listeners
I'm trying to make a dialogue system with events.
I have a DialogueEvent class that looks like this
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts.Dialogue
{
    [CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "ScriptableObjects/GameEvent/DialogueEvent")]
    public class DialogueEvent : ScriptableObject
    {
        public List<DialogueEventListener> listeners = new List<DialogueEventListener>();
       
        // Raise event through different methods

        public void Raise(Component sender, object data)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < listeners.Count; i++)
            {
                listeners[i].OnEventRaised(sender, data);
            }
        }

        // Manage Listeners

        public void RegisterListener(DialogueEventListener dialogueEventListener)
        {
            if(!listeners.Contains(dialogueEventListener))
            {
                listeners.Add(dialogueEventListener);
            }
        }

        public void UnregisterListener(DialogueEventListener dialogueEventListener)
        {
            if(listeners.Contains(dialogueEventListener))
            {
                listeners.Remove(dialogueEventListener);
            }
        }
    }
}

I also have a DialogueEventListener class that looks like this
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

namespace Assets.Scripts.Dialogue
{
    public class DialogueEventListener : MonoBehaviour
    {
        //
        // EVENT VARIABLES
        [SerializeField]
        private DialogueEvent dialogueEvent;
        [SerializeField]
        private CustomDialogueEvent response;
        public DialogueEvent DialogueEvent
        {
            get => dialogueEvent;
            set => dialogueEvent = value;
        }
        public CustomDialogueEvent Response
        {
            get => response;
            set => response = value;
        }
        
        
        // 
        // FUNCTIONS
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            dialogueEvent.RegisterListener(this);
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            dialogueEvent.UnregisterListener(this);
        }

        public void OnEventRaised(Component sender, object data)
        {
            response.Invoke(sender, data);
        }

    }
}

I have a gameObject with the DialogueEventListener script on it, but the DialogueEvent SO I made that the script references is not registering the listener.DialogueEvent ScriptableObject with serialized list of listeners
Since there is no reference I'm getting an NRE and it's screwing up the dialogue system.
I've tried manually adding the listener but it won't let me. Also, I've tried changing the listener functions to happen on awake but it doesn't work.
